# How to check if a string is alphanumeric and can contain white spaces in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to make a secure search querying with PHP.

So far, this is my code, which is incorrect:

```
else if(!ctype_alpha($searchkey) && !is_numeric($searchkey) &&!ctype_print($searchkey)){
    $data['errMsg'] = "Please enter a valid search key.";
}
```

Although `ctype_print` is kinda good, it still accepts non-alpha characters, which is unsafe to SQL injections. What can I use that will allow whitespaces but disallow non-alphanumeric characters? Thank you. All answers will be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

So I got it. Sometimes, I get so silly. To keep from getting unsafe inputs, I used PHP's `mysql_real_escape_string`. Sorry guys.

Comment: Are you using prepared statements?

Comment: No, I'm not using prepared statement. If I will use it, how so?

Comment: If it's just for SQL safety, as Neal said the use of prepared statements will help protect against injections. Otherwise if it's also another form of validation, you can just go for a simple regex.

Comment: What are you trying to protect against? If you're trying to mitigate SQL Injection just use a prepared statement. You can do some courtesy formatting checks client side with JS if you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
function coolCheck($string) {
    return preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/", $string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to defend against SQL Injection I would use a prepared statement (PDO example):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE input = ?');
$stmt->execute($searchkey);

foreach($stmt as $row){
    //do something
}
```

This is far more effective than any input sanitisation you can create.

If you're just looking to simply format the search query in a particular way please ignore this and use something like `ctype_alnum($searchKey)`, PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/', $searchkey);
```

Answer (score -1):

use `ctype_alnum()` function:

```
!ctype_alnum($searchkey)
```

this checks if string is alpha-numeric

Comment: ctype_alnum() does not allow white spaces